# setDefaultNightMode not working when using setTheme in main activity

Tags: android, themes, splash-screen

I have an app where I'm forcing "MODE_NIGHT_NO" in my main (and only) activity, I do this right after super.onCreate().

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

Now I'm adding a splash screen following [this guide](https://medium.com/android-news/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52), basically:

- Create a drawable for the splash screen
- Create a style in **values\themes.xml** called SplashScreen with parent AppTheme (AppTheme's parent is **Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar**)

  ```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Assign SplashTheme to the main activity in the Manifest

  ```
          android:name=".MainDrawerActivity"
          android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"...
  ```
- Lastly call setTheme in the main activity, before super.onCreate() to set the correct AppTheme for the whole app

  ```
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer)
  ```

The splash screen works, but the issues is that after the splash screen finishes, the theme is changed to dark mode. Even if the phone IS NOT in dark mode.

I've tried calling it like this, but it doesn't work either, same behavior:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_drawer)
```

I even tried deleting **values-night\themes.xml** to see what would happen, but same result. (I've restored said folder)

Why is it that setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO) is not working in the same way when adding setTheme(AppTheme)?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I realized I was setting the wrong theme to my activity in the setTheme() method. But even then, I'm not sure why it was showing the dark theme. I can't even recreate the issue now. It will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but I do not know why. I think this is the problem with the
Default material design theme. If you go to your theme files and just change the

```
 <style name="Theme.ContactForm" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
  <style name="Theme.ContactForm" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This should work Let me know if this can hlep.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Actually the problem was that I was setting the wrong theme (in setTheme()) =/ but even then, I still don't understand why it was setting the dark theme when the phone/emulator wasn't in dark mode, and I was using `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)` and now it's not even happening anymore if I try to recreate the issue! Pfff

Comment: You welcome My Friend. sometimes it happens. Just Apply do not give up and you will find the solution.